# Accessing a local variable from another class

Tags: java, local-variables

I was wondering if it is possible to access a local variable from another class in Java. I have tried to do it in the below code, however, it is giving an error. 
Please clarify whether this is possible, and how it may be done if it is.

```
class Human
{
    int age;
    int height;

    public static void main2()
    {
        String eye_colour="Blue";
    }

}
```

```
class Tobi_Brown 
{
    public static void main()
    {


Tobi_Brown a=new Tobi_Brown();

        System.out.println("The eye colour is " + Human.main2().eye_colour);//Accessing eye_colour
    }
}
```

Thanks is advance!

Comment: variable dies when the method ends

Comment: **local** kind of means that it is only accessible in their block (or inner block), even not in the same class, nor in a different block in the same method. Further, as Goldy commented, the variables only exist - *have* memory position - while the block (also the whole method can be considered one) they are declared in is active

Comment: needing such access is a sign that the whole design is not correct and should be changed (in questions example, eye color should be an attribute (field) of `Human`)

Comment: Refer Java Language Specification §6.3 [Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3). A quote: _The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears_ By the way, are you familiar with this? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are accessible inside the block (if-else/for/while) where they are declared. If you want to use any variables that belong to other classes, you can use static variables.

```
class Human
{
    public static String eye_color = "Blue";
    int age;
    int height;

    public static void main()
    {
    }

}
```

And you can access it in other classes like:

```
class Tobi_Brown 
{
    public static void main()
    {


Tobi_Brown a=new Tobi_Brown();

        System.out.println("The eye colour is " + Human.eye_colour);//Accessing eye_colour
    }
}
```

Comment: They're not even accessible within the _method_, they're accessible within the same _block_ (a local declared inside a loop body isn't accessible once you exit).

Comment: I would not make the field static (`Human`s may have different eye colors, and better example using created instance)

Answer (score 0):

`main2()` is a Method and can only return one value of a certain type or nothing. Everything else is lost after the method ends. Currently your return type is `void` thus returning nothing. If you change your return type from `void` to `String` and return the eye color you can use it.

```
public class Human {

    public static String main2() {
        String hairColor = "Red";
        String eye_colour = "Blue";
        return eye_colour;
        // hairColor is now lost.
    }

}

// In another class or the same.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String eyeColor = Human.main2();
    System.out.println("The eye colour is " + eyeColor);
}
```

Does this make sense through? Id say no. We want every human to have his own eye color. So if you have a human called `Tobi_Brown` with brown eye color, how can this be expressed with java code?

```
public class Human {

    public String eyeColor;
    public int age;
    public int height;

}

// Again in another class or the same.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Human tobiBrown = new Human();
    tobiBrown.eyeColor = "brown";
    Human sarahSora = new Human();
    sarahSora.eyeColor = "Sky blue";
    System.out.println("The eye colour is " + tobiBrown.eyeColor);
    System.out.println("The eye colour is " + sarahSora.eyeColor);
}
```

Notice how `tobiBrown` and `sarahSora` are both `Human` with just different `eye_colour`. `Human humanName = new Human()` creates a new object of type `Human`. Every human can have his own `eye_colour`, `age` and `height`.